# how much of this stuff we can channel

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Does **"channel"** in the provided context mean "to produce and consume"?

Context:

> Anand assumes that the objects she has gathered together constitute a
>   material culture of urban life that is both banal and deeply
>   historical. The land or soil continues to support the human histories
>   that ferry back and forth across it; many of these human histories go
>   undetected, moldering under layers of other objects and material in a
>   landfill. Perhaps Anand makes a plea for us as viewers to consider
>   making more conscious commitments to the objects that flow through our
>   lives and that possibly contain the meaning of our existences, which
>   should not merely be a function of how much of this stuff we can
>   **channel**. It is a plea for a slower and more deliberate way of living
>   with the objects we have around us (Art and politics by Claudia Mesch).

Comment: Given the earlier mention of *the objects that flow through our lives*, I would read *channel* as processing in a deliberate particular way.  It might include producing and consuming but could involve other reactions; I think the point here is that we ought to be thoughtful think about what we do with this stuff and be systematic in doing so.

Comment: @Henry you say "I would read channel as processing in a deliberate particular way". But it seems the opposite. I think it says that we should not only look at  everyday objects around us in a qualitative manner (i.e. how much of them we can channel or use or produce) but we should also think about their conceptual qualities and behave more thoughtfully.

Answer (score 1):

Channel has a variety of meanings, but the most contextual here, I think, is, 'Cause to pass along or through a specified route or medium.'

And, in this instance, IMHO, when the writer says 'channel', they mean, how much stuff passes into and then out of our lives without us giving slow and deliberate thought to its necessity, value or meaning.

They make a really good point. We don't give enough thought to the things we consume and are covering our beautiful planet in trash as a result.

HTH